# Binding values dynamically to jQuery multiselct control shows radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

I am getting response form Api and I am dynamically creating SELECT control with options.

This is my HTML

```
         <select id="resourceviewstop"></select>
```

I am looping response in Javascript as below

```
         $.each(response, function (index, item) {
             $('<option value="' + item.Id+ '">' + item.Description + '</option>').appendTo('#resourceviewstop');
          });
```

Normal drop down will be created as shown below.

[image]

Now I am trying to apply multiselect to generated drop down options using jQuery multiselect plugin

```
        $('#resourceviewstop').multiselect({
                 includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
```

[image]

But I see radio buttons instead of check box. How can i get checkbox here?

**EDITED**

If i hard code OPTIONS then it will come as checkbox :( But I am getting data from Json and can not hard code.

HTML generated, which i grabbed from developer tool

[image]

Comment: includeSelectAllOption: true ?

Comment: I made it includeSelectAllOption:true, still i get radio buttons :( EDITED the post.

Comment: i will come up with jsfiddle wait plz.

Comment: Can you give me exactly the html of this element you get?

Comment: added HTML in post, i took it from developer tool, fireBug, add i can see "radio" in HTML and javascript, updated POST

Comment: outstanding. Thanks a lot. I am sure it is useful to all multi-select users like me. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62063/discussion-between-isharehappycode-and-csdtesting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiselect has a special way to [add new option](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#refresh) items.You have to add multiselect('refresh') to render your new options:

Here is how to add a value: (http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/mpy72gyf/)

```
var el  = $('#resourceviewstop').multiselect({
         header:false,
         includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
var newItem = $('#newItem');
var opt =  opt = $('<option />');
    $("#add").click(function(){
        var v = newItem.val(), opt = $('<option />', {
            value: v,
            text: v
        });
        opt.appendTo(el);
        el.multiselect('refresh');
    });
```

So, you have to change the append operation to:

```
  $.each(response, function (index, item) {
    var opt = $('<option />', {
                value: item.Id,
                text: item.Description 
            });
            opt.appendTo(el);
            el.multiselect('refresh');
          });
```

Hope this helps!

Revisioned solution asked vol.1: http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/mpy72gyf/1/

vol2 http://jsfiddle.net/mpy72gyf/2/

Comment: @iShareHappyCode .You have to put as inout to your function the drop down element el like that http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/mpy72gyf/1/